# how to solve spark read hive orc file meet error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, orc

jdk 1.8
scala 2.12.11
spark 3.0.1

When I read hive table and write orc file in Scala Spark it is running successfully:

```
df.write.option("compression", "none").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).orc(dump_path)
```

When I read the  orc file from period-export-orc file in Python PySpark it is also running successfully:

`dfs = spark.read.orc("/Users/muller/Documents/gitcode/personEtl/knowledge_source_100.orc")`

But when I read the same period-export-orc in Scala Spark - the following error occurs:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.orc.impl.ReaderImpl cannot be cast to java.io.Closeable
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2538)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcUtils$.readSchema(OrcUtils.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcUtils$.$anonfun$readSchema$4(OrcUtils.scala:88)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.collectFirst(TraversableOnce.scala:172)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.collectFirst$(TraversableOnce.scala:159)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.collectFirst(Iterator.scala:1431)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcUtils$.readSchema(OrcUtils.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcUtils$.inferSchema(OrcUtils.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.inferSchema(OrcFileFormat.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.$anonfun$getOrInferFileFormatSchema$11(DataSource.scala:198)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:195)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:408)
```

Comment: in scala  spark  read orc file  like this

Comment: def loadORCByOne(path:String):DataFrame={
    val  spark :SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("sess").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    val df = spark.read.orc(path)
    df
  }

Comment: also meet same error in read  parquet file

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
As stack trace suggests that failure happens while executing *Utils.tryWithResource()* method. If you see the source code https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.0.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala, it is seen that it expects a "java.io.Closable" object.

"org.apache.orc.impl.ReaderImpl" is packaged inside *hive-exec-**.jar* which implements the "org.apache.orc.Reader" interface. hive-exec is a fat jar and it has all the dependencies packaged with the jar and its package "org.apache.orc.Reader" as well which does not extends the "java.io.Closable" class that is why this failure.

Please add https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/orc/orc-core/1.5.10/orc-core-1.5.10.jar into your spark driver/executor classpath, This jar extends Closable in "org.apache.orc.Reader" interface. The jar should be added at the beginning of the classpath so that the "org.apache.orc.Reader" from the "orc-core" jar should get load first and not from "hive-exec" jar.

This way I resolved the issue. I am not sure why in pyspark it worked. You can check the jars in driver/executor classpath from where "org.apache.orc.Reader" getting picked up.